# What is the best way to have actual execution plan and IO stats as values to insert?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, dynamic-sql, statistics

We have idea to create procedure which will test performance of query and insert specific information associated with executed query to table with test performance history (`[dbo].[TestHistory]`. We would like to collect:

1. `[ActualExecutionPlan] [XML] NOT NULL`
2. `[LogicalReads] [BIGINT] NOT NULL`
3. `[CPUTime] [BIGINT] NOT NULL`
4. `[ElapsedTime] [BIGINT] NULL`,
5. `[StartProcedureTime] [DATETIME2](7) NOT NULL`
6. `[EndProcedureTime] [DATETIME2](7) NOT NULL`
7. `[IndexNamesInDynamicSqlTableOrView] [VARCHAR](8000)`
8. `[RowCount] [INT] NOT NULL`
9. `[ViewDefinition] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL`

And insert these values after every execution of procedure with parameter.

So idea is to create procedure `[dbo].[TestQuery]` with parameter `@sqlQuery varchar(max)`. `@sqlQuery` will be query to execute as dynamic sql with header -> `SET STATISTICS XML,IO,TIME ON`.

### Question

Do you have idea how to get:

1. `[ActualExecutionPlan]` as xml
2. `[LogicalReads]`
3. `[CPUTime]`
4. `[ElapsedTime]`

As values to insert to `[dbo].[TestHistory]` table ? Is it any possibility to get it from "Messages" tab and result from `SET STATISTICS XML ON` ?

Comment: [A Little More Fun With Logging Dynamic SQL](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/starting-sql/starting-sql-a-little-more-fun-with-logging-dynamic-sql/)

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. That is what I need :) Just one question. Is this solution returning actual plan or estimated plan ?

Comment: @ErikDarling do you know why logical reads from `sys.dm_exec_requests` differ from stats from `SET STATISCTIS IO ON` / execution plan ? In `sys.dm_exec_requests` I got 439.00 reds where I see in `message tab`  only 3 reads. I am comparing your solution (dynamic sql) and just plain query with  `SET STATISCTIS IO, XML ON`